# Is there a way to give read permissions for a subdirectory in Deno?

Tags: permissions, deno, read-access

I have a script that accesses files in a sub-directory. It works when you allow all read access, but all of my attempts at giving read access only to that directory have failed. Is there a way to specify directories via relative paths for `--allow-read`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command

```
deno run --allow-read=./resources  .\testread.ts
```

gives you read access only to the subdirectory `./resources`

so this works:

```
const text1 = Deno.readTextFile("./resources/test.txt");
```

and this throws an exception:

```
const text1 = Deno.readTextFile("./test.txt");
```

> PermissionDenied: read access to "./test.txt", run again with the --allow-read flag

You can also specify more than one directory in a comma separated list:

```
deno run --allow-read=./resources,./other  .\testread.ts
```

If you need write access, it works the same way as for read access:

```
deno run --allow-write=./resources,./other  .\testread.ts
```

Reference: https://deno.land/manual/getting_started/permissions